# ExtJS 4 month and year picker

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I wanted to add a Month and Year picker on my app. So, I found this Fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h5i on one of stackoverflow posts. It uses Extjs 5.0 and works fine. However, if we change it to 4.2.1 the last row on the Month and Year both disappear i.e June, Dec on Months and 2015, 2020 on years disappear. The same can be seen when you choose Extjs 5.0.

What should I be fixing/changing to get those rows back? I tried increasing height/width of .x-monthpicer-body etc ... but didn't help much.

Comment: this can be ignored I guess. I fixed the issue 'temporarily' by changing the .x-monthpicker-body using px instead of %. Not sure if it will break during zoom in/outs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue 'temporarily' by changing the .x-monthpicker-body using px instead of %. Not sure if it will break during zoom in/outs.

Answer (score 0):

For Extjs 4 ive fixed this by adding simple css

check out [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) fiddle

i just added the following css code

```
.x-monthpicker {
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```