# Extjs 4.2 datefield show only year and month no date

Tags: extjs, overriding, datefield

I need to override the datefield dropdown to show only the year, month but no date.
And on selection the field should set the date in format YYYY-MM since i just want to set the year and month values in date field like 2018-03 or 2018-04

here is the [senchaFiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2f5o)

[image]

[image: year and month only]

I just want the second image like dropdown(just showing the year and month) to show on the datefield dropdown without showing the dates

Comment: OK ive just edited the question and added senchafiddle

Comment: Can you check whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281312/extjs-4-month-and-year-picker) is what you need?

Comment: yes thankyou @Alexander that is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Alexander but there was an issue for the version extjs 4. ive managed it and posted on [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2f8r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok ive just tried this and it worked greatly also for extjs4

here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)

Answer (score 0):

Month Year date field is shown as from @Alexander's answer in this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/h5i&view/editor).

Another option is using stock date picker with the [monthPickerPlugin](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?76187-datePicker-month-and-year-only)